# How to output to a text file with indentation

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and am trying to output the results of a form to a text file with indentation. I have read the documentation and can only find a writer for writing CSV output. Ultimately I'm trying to generate a downloadable Python script based on inputs from a form. Since the Python requires accurate indentation, I'm having trouble outputting correctly.

Here is part of my view that im using to generate output:

```
if form.is_valid():
        ServerName = form.cleaned_data.get('ServerName')
        response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/plain')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=script.py' 
        writer = csv.writer(response)
        writer.writerow(['def ping ():'])
        writer.writerow(['run ('ping ServerName')])
return response
```

I would like the output of the script.py to be like this:

```
def ping():
    run('ping server01')
```

Questions:

1. Am I using the correct writer to output to a text file?
2. How do I add indentation to my output?
3. How to I add brackets i.e.: `( )`  or quotes `' '` to the output without getting errors in the view.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you already generated your complete python script structure and you just want to write it out to the response? Or is this more of a compound question including how to properly compose the python sytax into valid structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to be able to write out a literal raw representation of your text, in a way that will also protect you from possible escaping issues, just use a triple quote and maybe some simple dict keyword formatting:

```
ServerName = form.cleaned_data.get('ServerName')

py_script = """
def ping():
    run('ping %(ServerName)s')
""" % locals()

response.write(py_script)
```

Or with more values:

```
ServerName = form.cleaned_data.get('ServerName')
foo = 'foo'
bar = 'bar'

py_script = """
def ping():
    run('ping %(ServerName)s')
    print "[%(foo)s]"
    print '(%(bar)s)'
""" % locals()

response.write(py_script)
```

Comment: This method seemed to write everything on the same line without any indentation

Comment: It should be preserving the raw formatting. Are you looking at it with a plain text mime type? If you print that string, you will see newlines in it

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects):

> ...if you want to add content incrementally, you can use response as a file-like object:

```
response = HttpResponse()
response.write("<p>Here's the text of the Web page.</p>")
response.write("<p>Here's another paragraph.</p>")
```

Thus just write to your response:

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/plain')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=script.py'
response.write("def ping(): \n")
response.write("    run('ping server01')\n")
```